# Concentric circles texture on RingGeometry

Tags: three.js

I am trying to create a flat ring in three.js with a concentric circles texture, like Saturn's rings. I cannot manage to do anything but lines that radiate from the center (like a bicycle wheel), no matter what I put in the image. It seems that textures are applied to RingGeometry in a very different fashion than CircleGeometry.

I could easily apply a concentric circles texture to a CircleGeometry, but a ring (with a hole in the middle) is really what I need. Is anybody aware of a way to have textures on rings do something else than radiate?

I did not find a way in Three.js documentation, nor on the web, to do what I want, as it seems that rings are seldom used by anybody...

Thank you

Comment: This question have been answered in this other one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633913/non-radial-texture-mapping-over-a-ring-geometry-in-webgl-using-three-js

Answer (score 1):

Go here http://jsfiddle.net/theo/VsWb9/  and replace

```
geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(200, 200, 200);
material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

with

```
geometry    = new THREE.TorusGeometry( 100, .5 , 50 ,50); 
material    = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial(); 
mesh    = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```

If you want to change the ring color to say black for instance 
change

```
material    = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
```

to

```
material    = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x000});
```

Stick any other material changes in that array input argument to the constructor
function THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({**arguments here**})

Answer (score 0):

I found this for making the geometry. It creates a disk of theataSeegmens triangles

```
this.RingGeometry = function ( innerRadius, outerRadius, thetaSegments) {

        THREE.Geometry.call( this )

        innerRadius = innerRadius || 0
        outerRadius = outerRadius || 50
        thetaSegments   = thetaSegments || 8
        innerRadius*=Obj.Size*100;
        outerRadius*=Obj.Size*100;

        var normal  = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 )

        for(var i = 0; i < thetaSegments; i++ ){
            var angleLo = (i / thetaSegments) *Math.PI*2
            var angleHi = ((i+1) / thetaSegments) *Math.PI*2

            var vertex1 = new THREE.Vector3(innerRadius * Math.cos(angleLo), innerRadius * Math.sin(angleLo), 0);
            var vertex2 = new THREE.Vector3(outerRadius * Math.cos(angleLo), outerRadius * Math.sin(angleLo), 0);
            var vertex3 = new THREE.Vector3(innerRadius * Math.cos(angleHi), innerRadius * Math.sin(angleHi), 0);
            var vertex4 = new THREE.Vector3(outerRadius * Math.cos(angleHi), outerRadius * Math.sin(angleHi), 0);

            this.vertices.push( vertex1 );
            this.vertices.push( vertex2 );
            this.vertices.push( vertex3 );
            this.vertices.push( vertex4 );


            var vertexIdx   = i * 4;

            // Create the first triangle
            var face = new THREE.Face3(vertexIdx + 0, vertexIdx + 1, vertexIdx + 2, normal);
            var uvs = []

            var uv = new THREE.Vector2(0, 0)
            uvs.push(uv)
            var uv = new THREE.Vector2(1, 0)
            uvs.push(uv)
            var uv = new THREE.Vector2(0, 1)
            uvs.push(uv)

            this.faces.push(face);
            this.faceVertexUvs[0].push(uvs);

            // Create the second triangle
            var face = new THREE.Face3(vertexIdx + 2, vertexIdx + 1, vertexIdx + 3, normal);
            var uvs = []

            var uv = new THREE.Vector2(0, 1)
            uvs.push(uv)
            var uv = new THREE.Vector2(1, 0)
            uvs.push(uv)
            var uv = new THREE.Vector2(1, 1)
            uvs.push(uv)

            this.faces.push(face);
            this.faceVertexUvs[0].push(uvs);
    }

    //this.computeCentroids();
    //this.computeFaceNormals();

    this.boundingSphere = new THREE.Sphere( new THREE.Vector3(), outerRadius );

};
this.RingGeometry.prototype = Object.create( THREE.Geometry.prototype );
```

The above line is important to get it to work.
Here is a sugestion how to set the ring material.assuming that you have two pictures (just a sqare section) that can be used for alphamap and for 
the actual ring.

```
var ringMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( 
            {           
                    map: SaturnRingColor,       
                    alphaMap:SaturnRingPattern,
                    color: 0xffffff, 
                    specular: 0x555555, 
                    shininess: 3,
                    emissive:10,
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                    castshadow:true,
                    transparent : true,
                    opacity     : 0.9,
            } );


        this.ringMesh = new THREE.Mesh( this.RingGeometry , RingMaterial );
```