# Non-radial texture mapping over a ring geometry in WebGL using Three.js

Tags: opengl-es, three.js, mapping, textures

I am trying to simulate image deformation effects using textures over 2D geomtries using the ThreeJS library. I want to apply a texture image over a hollow circle (basically, a ring built by the THREE.RingGeometry function) and obtain the results shown at this image:

[image: Texture image and desired results]

Following I show the results I am obtaining in my scene both for the solid ring and its wireframed version:

[image: Texture applied over the ring and its corresponding wireframed version]

The problem is that, as you see, the texture is been applied in a radial way, from the center of the ring to the outside. However, what I really need is to apply the texture image on a concentric circle way, as shown in the first image of this question.

The idea is to produce a deformed version of the original texture over a ring shape. I would like to know how this effect can be programmatically achieved through Three.js in such a way that the destination shape can be any arbitrary 2D geometry .

Following, there is the relevant code I am using to draw my scene:

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./images/texture.png');

var wireRing = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.RingGeometry(10, 20, 50, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture, wireframe: true}));
wireRing.position.set(-25, 50, 0);
scene.add(wireRing);

var ring = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.RingGeometry(10, 20, 50, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture}));
ring.position.set(25, 50, 0);
scene.add(ring);
```

Comment: What code do you have so far? Can you edit your question to add your code?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have update the message to show the relevant code portion that I am using to draw the scene. The entire html file and other resources are published at https://www.dropbox.com/s/6t097e1y0utcenh/Code.zip

Comment: I'd suggest you download the code to three.js and look at the RingGeometry function. It sounds like you just want to swap texture coordinates. Basically line# 32 in [RingGeometry.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/geometries/RingGeometry.js). Swap the 2 parts around the comma. Either that or rotate your image 90 degrees.

Comment: Hi @gman, thanks for your comment. I have modified the RingGeometry function as you suggest with no success. The texture mapping is still radial but it appears rotated. This also happens when the texture image is rotated 90 degrees. I am pretty sure this has to do with the UV configuration but can't find a way to solve it. :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change the UV mapping in `RingGeometry` like so:

```
uvs.push( new THREE.Vector2( o / thetaSegments, i / phiSegments ) );
```

Also, if you want to rotate the texture around the ring, you instantiate the `RingGeometry` by varying the `thetaStart` parameter:

```
var geometry = new THREE.RingGeometry( 10, 20, 50, 5, thetaStart, Math.PI * 2 );
```

three.js r.67

Comment: Thank you very much @WestLangley, your solution indeed worked perfectly for the ring! Just a last question... The UV mapping should be always modified for any geometry used in case that the common plane mapping is not desired? What if the destination geometry had any other generic shape?

Comment: ANY other geometric shape? You are asking a lot, no?