# How can I apply a radial texture to a ring with three.js r67?

Tags: javascript, three.js, texture-mapping

I am trying to apply a texture to a ringGeometry in three.js r67.  I cannot get the texture oriented correctly. I would like to apply the following texture to a ringGeometry mesh radially, so that the blue end of the texture appears on the ring's inner circumference and the red end appears on the outer circumference. Here is the relevant portion of my code with JSFiddle link to a running example:

```
geometry = new THREE.RingGeometry(100, 192, 60);
material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: texture });
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mareid/8t4cz/4/

I can't get the texture to (a) flow radially, (b) line up with the radial extent of the ring, so that the entire texture is displayed, and (c) appear on both sides of the ring. I want it to appear more like this:

[http://astro.utoronto.ca/~mreid/ring_gradient.png](http://astro.utoronto.ca/%7Emreid/ring_gradient.png)

I have a very shaky grasp of UV mapping. Note that the texture I have provided is just an example. I would like to be able to do this in the general case of radial textures on rings.

Someone else posted a similar question, but I can't figure out how to adapt the UV mapping from their example to mine:

[Non-radial texture mapping over a ring geometry in WebGL using Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633913/non-radial-texture-mapping-over-a-ring-geometry-in-webgl-using-three-js)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would you consider using something similar to `ring_gradient.png` as your texture, instead?

Comment: I would say that the code in the answer that you link has the exact answer that you are looking for, no need to adapt code. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @vals, I tried changing the uv mapping using the code in that link. It orients the texture in the correct direction (i.e. radially), but only a small portion of the texture is actually mapped onto the ring. That is, if I were to make the texture five colored bands (say red, orange, yellow, green, blue), the result are red and orange concentric circles, but no yellow, green, or blue. I can't figure out how to get the rest of the texture to show up. It's like 10% of the texture is mapped to 100% of the radial extent of the ring, instead of 100% to 100%.

Comment: @vals I've implemented your solution, and you can see that it doesn't quite work:
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/mareid/8t4cz/5/)
Try changing the last two numbers in the following line and you'll see some weird behaviour of both the geometry and the texture. It's like it self-shadows itself.  Very odd. You only get the full texture if thetaSegments=phiSegments, I think, and even then with a funny self-shadow on the ring.

Comment: it isn't my solution :-)  Anyway, I think that the code is slightly wrong, it should be   uvs.push( new THREE.Vector2( i/(thetaSegments-1), o/ (phiSegments-1) ) );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of experimentation, I can confirm that the solution shared on the thread I linked and advocated by @vals does actually work, but there was one detail missing from the solution that was needed for a novice like me.  So, to summarize, to apply a radial texture to a RingGeometry, you need to modify the uv mapping in three.js (r67, in this case) to be like this:

```
//uvs.push( new THREE.Vector2( ( vertex.x / outerRadius+1)/2, ( vertex.y / outerRadius + 1 ) / 2 ) );
uvs.push( new THREE.Vector2( i/(thetaSegments-1), o/ (phiSegments-1) ) );
```

You then also need to ensure that, when you call RingGeometry, you set thetaSegments and phiSegments to the same number.  Otherwise, only part of the texture will appear on the ring.  I hope this helps someone.  Thanks @vals and @WestLangley for your help.

Answer (score 4):

My use case was to display the rings around Saturn using a radial texture. The following code is a direct excerpt based on three.js r84.

```
var segs = 96;
var ii = radius * 1.200;
var oo = radius * 1.950;

var geometry = new THREE.RingBufferGeometry(ii, oo, segs);

var uvs = geometry.attributes.uv.array;
// loop and initialization taken from RingBufferGeometry
var phiSegments = geometry.parameters.phiSegments || 0;
var thetaSegments = geometry.parameters.thetaSegments || 0;
phiSegments = phiSegments !== undefined ? Math.max( 1, phiSegments ) : 1;
thetaSegments = thetaSegments !== undefined ? Math.max( 3, thetaSegments ) : 8;
for ( var c = 0, j = 0; j <= phiSegments; j ++ ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i <= thetaSegments; i ++ ) {
        uvs[c++] = i / thetaSegments,
        uvs[c++] = j / phiSegments;
    }
}
```